# Is it O.K to eliminate 'a' tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I get tired of the dotted box that appears when you click a tags...so that I started replacing them with p tags...and adding an event listener for click events.

I can't help but notice that other popular sites don't do this ( for example when you click Post Your Question on SO the annoying dotted box appears )

Is there any good reason not to replace a tags by p tags.  I don't need any of the special a tag properties...in fact I have to use preventDefault() in my JavaScript to stop them from linking some times.

Is it O.K to pretty much eliminate the A tag?

This is a question regarding major modern browsers.

I'm about to rid myself of them...and am paranoid I'm missing something as I see them still in use pretty much everywhere.

Comment: What is the dotted box that appears when you click an `<a>` tag?

Comment: `<a>` is stayed in HTML5 for a reason.

Comment: You may hide the outline using CSS

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - `outline: none;`

Comment: At first, I thought this question was satire. Then, I came to a horrible realization...mostly that this was not satire. Huge wtf moment ensued. Haven't you ever heard of "accessibility"? Or maybe a more well known phrase "Search Engine Optimization"? Don't just go assuming that you can remove convention that just about every site on the internet conforms to - especially not just to appease your own tastes. We are all in this together!

Comment: Please read http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-remove-css-outlines-in-an-accessible-manner/

Answer (score 11):

No, this is **not** okay.

Anchor tags are needed for browsers that don't support your styling, and I'm just talking about old versions of IE.  Remember that screen readers, text-only users, and browser plugins all expect to find your anchor tags.

As Dash has pointed out, bots such as search engine crawlers also need your anchor tags to be able to follow them and index your pages.

HTML is for document structure.  CSS is for styling.  It is important to keep this principal.

A note regarding that dotted box... that is there to show focus on an element.  Not everyone uses a mouse you know.  Some prefer to tab through the document with a keyboard, and that focus box helps with that.  Even if you succeed in removing it with CSS... please don't.

Comment: +1 Also remember that Search Engines will be interested in what links are present on a site, so this functional change could result in your site being driven down the Google rankings, for example.

Comment: @dash, YES!  How could I forget?  Hiro, Dash brings up a very important point here about bots, whether they are search engines, or others.

Comment: ....note that SO is not consistent...with their outlines...the top menu items->Question,Tags,User...do not have the outline...while the top top ( very top ) menu items do have an outline on tab....seems a bit random.

Comment: what have you say to SO's use of links with with out outlines?...are they at fault...is it a matter of preference perhaps?  they are at fault in their in-consistency...but not on whether they chose to have or not have out-lines...for me I'd prefer a little arrow that shows the focus as it allows tabbing and is more obvious then outlines that seem to be left their by accident and not actually placed there purposefully.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist, I'm not sure what you're talking about... I get focus boxes on all relevant elements on StackOverflow.  I must use a different browser than you.

Comment: more specifically, Firefox does not have outlines on the top menu items that I mentioned....Questions, Tags, Users...but the top menu items do.

Comment: more specifically, Safari does not have any outlines on click and it does not let you tab through the items all together.

Comment: In Firefox, twitter allows tabbing through links...but once again no dotted lines for a visual clue...but you can see a link display in the lower left hand corner

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this, because of html semantics. Screen readers and search engines may not be able to follow your link, for example.

Comment: In addition to people who have disabled javascript in their browser for security reasons (or corporate policy.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want buttons and links to have a dotted box around them after they've been clicked, simply add a listener that blurs the element:

```
<a href="..." onclick="this.blur();">Look ma, no dots</a>
```

There is also a CSS property you can set to not have dots too, but I can't remember it. Do a search or look at the Mozilla default stylesheet.